# very complex quotes in python/shell string

Tags: python, bash, shell, expect, pexpect

I have a very long string ssh_cmd, I get it from

```
cmd = """kill -9 `ps -ef|grep "udp_receiver"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}'`"""
HostName="133.33.22.1"
ssh_cmd = """ssh -t inria_spoofing@{0} 'sudo nohup bash -c "{1} > /nohup.out 2>&1 &"'""".format(HostName, cmd)
```

the resulted `ssh_cmd` is:

```
ssh -t kitty@133.33.22.1 'sudo nohup bash -c "kill -9 `ps -ef|grep "udp_receiver"|grep -v "grep"|awk '{print $2}'` > /nohup.out 2>&1 &"'
```

however, I'm afraid when I run

```
child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_cmd)
```

there is problem，
so how to organize the string?
thanks!

Comment: the result string is not a correct shell string

Comment: I'd suggest you to copy small shell-file to /tmp on destination machine and execute it without all this nighmare with quotations.

Comment: Also looks like you are solving wrong problem. Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Is using [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org) an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question, here's the proper `ssh_cmd`: `` ssh -t kitty@133.33.22.1 "sudo nohup bash -c \"kill -9 \\\`ps -ef | grep 'udp_receiver' | grep -v 'grep' | awk '{print \\\$2}'\\\` > /nohup.out 2>&1 &\"" ``

Basically, you need to escape double quotes, backticks and backslashes in a command each time you embed this command in another one. I did not use single quotes except at the lower level because you cannot use escaped single quotes inside single quotes.

You do need to escape the `$` too when it is just a character inside a string quoted with double quotes, even if the string does also contain single quotes.